# Display images one by one

Tags: android

Hi i want to display the imageviews one by one that means if image1 is displayed after 2 sec another image is displayed .but i don't want to use threads why because my application is small.I want to use handlers.So give me some suggestions,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one thing for displaying images in imageview at 2 sec's interval: `Implement Timer Control`.

And write image setting code on `onTick` method of `CountDownTimer` class.

```
 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
       imgView1.setImageResource(imgValue);
    }
```

You can refer  [This example](http://helloandroidworld.com/2010/02/how-to-create-a-simple-android-countdown-timer/)  and implement something like that.

Enjoy!!